# Laravel paypal cancel and advance payment with detail

Tags: laravel, paypal

How I can add student ID in the paypal payment request so whenever Any student cancel payment from paypal I will get the student ID in the response so i can store in the database. Also if I get advance payment notification from webhook so I know which student payment is successfully processed. I am use laravel paypal package for this. Can anyone please let me know how I can get this. And also how i can cancel payment from my side.

I am using this package https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal.

```
$provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
        $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal')); // Pull values from Config
        $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
        $provider->setAccessToken($token);
        $response = $provider->addProduct('Demo Product', 'Demo Product', 'SERVICE', 'SOFTWARE')
        ->addDailyPlan('Demo Plan', 'Demo Plan', 10.50)
        ->setReturnAndCancelUrl('https://example.com/paypal-success', 'https://example.com/paypal-cancel')
        ->setupSubscription('John Doe', 'john@example.com', '2023-02-21T15:47:00+00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal REST API parameter to set is `custom_id` in the create subscription API call, alongside the `plan_id`.

Then subscribe to the webhook event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`, which will notify of the initial as well as all future payments. The webhook will have the custom_id value in its payload for reconciliation. Use this event to keep track of the subscription's "valid through" date--if you don't receive a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event in time, the subscription has lapsed.